# Longest phrase in Tweet - Python timeout

Tags: python, algorithm, twitter, timeout, time-complexity

**Input** - array / list a, constant k

**Output** - Length of Longest sublist/subarray with sum <=k

E.g. given

> I am Bob

i.e. array `[1,2,3]` and k=3

Sublists possible are `[1],[2],[3],[1,2]`

Longest sublist here is `[1,2]`

*Length* = 2

Issue - TimeOut error in Python on Hackerrank

**Time Complexity** - 1 for loop - O(n)

**Space complexity** O(n)

`def  maxLength(a, k):
    lenmax=0
    dummy=[]
    for i in a:
        dummy.append(i)
        if sum(dummy)<=k:
            lenmax=max(lenmax,len(dummy))
        else:
            del dummy[0]
    return lenmax`

Comment: What is the actual problem with your code?  A timeout on hackerrank is not an issue.

Comment: looks like it exceeded the limit exceeded for executing a particular test case. Hence had to resolve it by removing time-intensive operations. e.g. sum of entire list

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by replacing the time-intensive operation

Time-out occurs when it exceeds the time limit set by HackerRank for every environment ["HackerRank TimeOut"](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment)

**Solution**

> Replace sum() function by a variable

In worst case, sum(list) would take O(n^2) time if the entire list was to be summed up all the time.

Instead, maintaining a variable would mean O(n) for the entire function as O(1) for updating a variable.

```
def  maxLength(a, k):
lenmax=0
dummy=[]
sumdummy=0
for i in a:
    dummy.append(i)
    sumdummy+=i
    if sumdummy<=k:
        lenmax=max(lenmax,len(dummy))
    else:
        sumdummy-=dummy[0]
        del dummy[0]

return lenmax
```